# Constructor's implicit parameter list can't refer to explicit argument?

Tags: scala, constructor, implicit, path-dependent-type, singleton-type

With a function, an implicit parameter can have an `arg.type` where `arg` is in the explicit parameter list. But apparently, not with a class:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_51).

scala> trait Applicable[A]
defined trait Applicable

scala> def f(a: AnyRef)(implicit ev: Applicable[a.type]): a.type = ???
f: (a: AnyRef)(implicit ev: Applicable[a.type])a.type

scala> case class Kniption(a: AnyRef)(implicit ev: Applicable[a.type])
<console>:8: error: not found: value a
       case class Kniption(a: AnyRef)(implicit ev: Applicable[a.type])
                                                              ^
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Applicable[a.type]
 required: Applicable[a.type]
       case class Kniption(a: AnyRef)(implicit ev: Applicable[a.type])
                                               ^
```

Is this a bug or a feature? If this behavior makes sense, can you explain why?

Comment: I believe it's a bug, and the issue I opened for it wasn't closed https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9491.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in class definition for scala it's not enough information for types inference.
What about defining Kniption parametrized:

```
case class Kniption[T](a: T)(implicit ev: Applicable[T])
```

Comment: That works, but I'd prefer not to add a type parameter because then I'll have to state the type parameter everywhere in the program where I have a Kniption object. I'd prefer to be able to just refer to plain Kniption objects and assume that each has an appropriate Applicable object.

Comment: you can do it like this: `sealed trait AnyKniption { type Arg <: AnyRef }` then
`case class Kniption[T <: AnyRef](a: T)(implicit ev: Applicable[T]) extends AnyKniption { type Arg = T }`. Now you can refer to `AnyKniption` without parameter and have a precise type of the arg: `Kniption#Arg`